# Select only specific file extensions using regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

Looking for a regex in notepad to filter and eliminate files of .AAA extension. Here is an example:

```
test it.AAA'
NOT NEW SO.BBB'
FULLFORT.CCA'
ASDASD.123'
SDSAD.AAA'
ASDA.322'
```

The result I am looking for is:

```
NOT NEW SO.BBB'
FULLFORT.CCA'
ASDASD.123'    
ASDA.322'
```

It is good if spaces are removed but fine without too. Using notepad++

EDIT: I have edited to exlcude the files of .AAA rather than selecting them.

EDIT2: Sorry I am actually looking for the file extensions in another text file, so they are all strings and I showed only the last portion of the strings.

Comment: Sorry I just edited the result..please see the edit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find:

```
^.*\.AAA'$
```

Replace with nothing.

If necessary, select all and delete the blank lines with **TextFX > TextFX Edit > Delete Blank Lines**.

Comment: looking for strings having no .AAA' as the trailing characters

Comment: Yeah, you're looking to "filter and eliminate files of .AAA extension". That's what my answer does.

Comment: @BoltClock: +1 for straight forward solution. Wouldn't `^.*(?!\.AAA)'$` work as well?

Comment: @Ancide: Nah, Notepad++ doesn't support lookahead/lookbehind assertions. And what would the replacement be for that?

Comment: @BoltClock I see. This wouldn't replace anything, just exclude all results ending in `.AAA'`. But since notepad++ doesn't support this, it doesn't matter :)

Answer (score 1):

(updated)

See the [wiki doc](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Regular_Expressions).  Or search for ".*\.AAA'$", replace with nothing.  This will leave a blank line.  If you want to clean those up, select all, then 
    `TextFX.TextFX Edit.Delete Blank Lines`

Comment: Remove spaces in a separate pass.  Regex not needed - just normal search/replace.

Comment: how can exlcude only those files having .AAA extension?

Comment: it is actually big string before the extension..it is like 23432dgdf dsfd.ABC, DFD_33_34.AAA in which I would like to see only non .aaa extension records

Comment: @Ram: So you mean some lines have multiple comma-separated filenames too and you want to take those into account as well? You should have said so...

Comment: Updated answer to clarify, insert missing \`.  If there can be multiple occurrences on a line, show the syntax.  This answer only deals with end-of-line cases.

Comment: @ed gave you credit as your answer was correct but I later edited my post

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
(.xls|.csv)$
```